# vue computed : add new computed value from created lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm beginner in vue

I'm trying to push a computed data with name , that name come from vuex which comes after creating the instance

How can i push new computed property to the instance in the created() hook ??

Here is the code

```
computed: {
            // 3 - i want to extract the object properties here computed 
            // that is easy bu using spread operator ...
            // Problem : vue intialize computed before the created() hook
            // so the spreed work befor passing the filling the object
            ...this.mapGettersObj
        },

        created(){
            // 1- i can access only this line after creating the object
            this.stocks = this.$store.state
            let arr=[]
            for (let stock in this.stocks){
                arr.push(stock+'Getter')
            }
            // 2 - mapGetters returns an object
            this.mapGettersObj=mapGetters(arr)
        }
```

If I can create new computed value after creating that will solve the problem

Comment: Please include the code you're working on and indicate what you've already tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: i have inserted the code

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in beforeCreate hook。

```
beforeCreate: function() {
  this.$options.computed = {
     demo2: function() {
       return this.demo
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing what you do, but if you want to have a variable available before the computed is called you can use beforeCreate hook: https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/

You could also do something in the lines of

```
computed: {
        ...function() {
            this.stocks = this.$store.state
            let arr=[]
            for (let stock in this.stocks){
                arr.push(stock+'Getter')
            }
            return mapGetters(arr);
        }();
    },
```

Comment: i think its a good idea

but this doesn't solve because the this.$store is created only after the component is created and isn't valid before creation time

so when calling computed object before creating the component it doesn't see this.$store.state

Comment: thank you
i think its a good idea

but this doesn't solve because the this.$store is created only after the component is created and isn't valid before creation time

so when calling computed object before creating the component it doesn't see this.$store.state

i was asking about pushing new computed data to computed object after creating the element , Is that possible ?

Comment: i have another solution 
but beforeCreate() hook run before creating test-component so it give error because  : i use an object which is created inside test-component
, wrong sequence

Comment: thanks Gerardo Rosciano  i was asking about pushing new computed data to computed object after creating the element , Is that possible ?

Comment: Sorry mustafa, i'm not sure.